# How can I choose the default user account for Windows 10 (technical preview)

Tags: user-accounts, windows-10-preview

On my computer, I have two accounts: my account (password protected) and a second one, without a password.
Each time Windows 10 (technical preview) starts, it automatically logs-in the second account, so I have to log-out and choose my own account.

Is there a way I can prevent that behavior? I was unable to find any settings for this.

I deleted the second account and recreated it but it didn't help.

PS: Windows 10 it is not a clean install (it's windows 7 updated to windows 10)

Comment: this also happens in Windows 8. Try if the tool also works in Windows 10: http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.206

Comment: It seems that it's not working. Thank you for answering me.

Comment: ask the author of the tool if he can find a way to get it working in Windows 10.

Comment: I enabled this setting in Users accounts (something like): Press Ctrl+Alt+Del before Log In and it's fine for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @popas You can "answer" your own question rather than comment it.

Comment: @Moab I know, but I considered that's not a good answer for my problem. When Windows starts I want to be able to select the desired account without needing to press any keys combination.

Comment: @popas, Actually there is a way those at winaero.com discussed on [this post](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-automatic-logon-of-last-user-in-window-8/). Some keys or string names might not be the same, that's why you don't get it to work automatically. Therefore I suggest you do it manually, but before that backup your registry and create a restore point.

Comment: Could you comment on whether the methods work or not (and why) from the article [Log On User Account Automatically at Windows 8 Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2894-log-user-account-automatically-windows-8-startup.html).

Comment: Erlis D. I did it manually / harrymc I applied step 5. None of them worked. It's still log's in (with my username). Thank you!

Comment: Try to use Option Two in the above article by, in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`, setting `AutoAdminLogon` to 0 and setting to empty `DefaultDomainName`, `DefaultUserName` and `DefaultPassword`.

Comment: [this may help](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/VCL/How+to+Configure+the+Windows+Default+User+Profile)

Comment: @harrymc Still nothing. I even deleted AutoLogonSID, but with no luck

Comment: I ended up by setting passwords for both accounts. At least none of them is automatically logged in.

Answer (score 1):

First open the Run dialog box by:

```
Windows XP:  Start -> Run
Windows 7/10: Start -> Type "run" (no quotes) and select when shows or
(All Windows versions): [Windows Key] + [R]  (very quick way of bringing it up)
```

Then in the Run dialog box, put `control userpasswords2<ENTER>`

You should be able to resolve your problem from there.

Comment: -1   No. It has been replaced in win10 by `netplwiz` https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/what-has-replaced-the-control-userpasswords2/3247dd60-cdaf-4d3b-81c0-7460a44afc05

Comment: Why 2 downvotes?  This does still work in Windows 10.  It wasn't disabled, just the 2nd option added.  Read the article you linked to (yes I am just now seeing the response). I also just tested on Windows 10 - both work.

Comment: The thing you wrote says to do start..run, but  by default there is no start..run in windows 10, it got retired in windows 7. The last OS to have it was win xp.  If you want to say anything about the run dialog in 10 then just say bring up the run dialog box , or state how i.e. to use winkey + R, or to change some settings to add it to the start menu but don't say to do start..run when that route to the run dialog doesn't exist.  It makes even your very first word "start", wrong.

Comment: And worse still, often somebody is looking for that 'control userpasswords2' command to work and can't get to it because they see no start..run.. And yet the very first thing you write in your "answer" is start...run, which is often what they even looked for straight away and often its non-existence in win10 or win7, is even the reason for the question in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll go ahead and go back and edit that if still possible.  Honestly have been so used to [Windows Key] + [R] for so long that I didn't think about it.  As one clarification here: If you hit [Start], the type "run" in both Windows 7 and 10, the Run command will show up in the results.  Also, you can still find it in the start menu, just not in the same spot as before.

Comment: well fixed, though you comment "If you hit [Start], the type "run" in both Windows 7 and 10, the Run command will show up in the results. Also, you can still find it in the start menu, just not in the same spot as before."    <-- Re that second sentence, do you mean if you do the first sentence?  Or do you mean that even without doing the first sentence, run is somewhere in the menu just not in the same place as earlier versions?  I think you will find that (aside from typing it and getting run in the results), run is by default not in the start menu in w7/w10, but it can be added.

Comment: Windows 10: Start -> Windows System -> Run

......Windows 7: Start -> Accessories -> Run

.......(both = default setups, at least for Pro versions.  Haven't tested on Home versions, in case that's different).....And sorry for the formatting, apparently you cannot add line breaks in comments..

Comment: thanks, that is interesting, I Hadn't heard of it in accessories.. what an absurd place for them to put it,  just checked in w7 and I see it there. There is a setting to, besides that,  add it in a better place, (still not the clear place it was in xp) but in w7, right clicking the taskbar or orb, then properties...start menu..customize... scroll down..click 'run command' ok.  Then it appears just below "help and support" in the start menu, which is a bit above the 'log off' etc options so near the bottom of the right hand column of the orb/start menu.

Comment: It's always interesting to find where in the world Microsoft hides things many of us grow to rely on.  Drives me nuts that to get to Internet Explorer in Windows 10, you have to go to Start -> Windows Accessories -> Internet Explorer.  Of course, that one seems to be b/c they are trying to push everyone to use Edge.  In some situations (like where I work), IE is still the only real option.

Comment: when I used IE, if I wasn't clicking an icon,  I always typed iexplore<ENTER> within the run dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a partial solution to this problem by trial and error.
All accounts require a password. Open `netplwiz` and select the account you want to log in with. Uncheck the 'Users must enter a password' checkbox and you will enter the password of the selected account. Now you're good to go as long as you're happy with logging in without a password. If you want to require a password, recheck the box. Now it will default to the lock screen of the last user.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: why do you say this is a partial solution and not a solution?